# AMP.goBack between different pages

Tags: google-amp

I couldn't figure out why AMP.goBack (on tap of button) didn't go back 1 page, like when you click the back button on the browser.

I found this: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5225

It's still open since March of 2017, so clearly the community has no need for a back button that spans different pages in an AMP document (I refuse to bind multiple documents into 1 page just for the sake of using a back button, the payload would be too much and asking a developer to take care of 1 big page is unreasonable and opens it up for way more issues than necessary)

Staying within the AMP space, and having their validater validate you still, how would one add a "history.back" to an AMP page?

Our site implementation is pure AMP for now, with the idea of PWA later-on (with AMP pages being loaded within PWA)

I can't understand why an AMP page (and the team behind the decision making) thought that having everything in 1 page seemed like a good idea.

Would love some feedback from someone who had this issue and what your work-around to this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interim, I've used an amp-form POST to my back-end, that uses the DOCUMENT_REFERRER replacement that AMP offers (because it doesn't offer it on all elements yet), to redirect back to the previous page. The caveat of this is that your "history" will always just be the previous page you were on. So if you were on Page A, navigated to Page B and click back, you'd go back to Page A. If you click back again, you'd navigate to Page B (and not the page you were on before Page A or B).

This implementation would have to do for now.